# C++ while loop code meaning

Tags: c++, loops

What does the `cin.ignore(256, '\n')` mean in the following code?

```
while (std::cin.fail()) {
    std::cout << "Please enter a mark from 1 to 100. Enter your first mark" << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(256,'\n');
    std::cin >> dblMarkOne;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It means to extract and discard the next 256 characters in the stream, or up until the next newline. Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Answer (score 1):

It will continue to skip characters until one of the two conditions are met

Condition 1 : number of skiped charecters = 256

Condition 2: a  '\n' charecter is found

So in your case it is starting reading from a new line

Answer (score 0):

It will ignore up to 256 characters that appear in the stream, or fewer if `'\n'` is found.

Its use in your example is a naive approach to a more robust solution using `getline`.

Answer (score 0):

It's ignoring characters a maximum of 256 times or up to the newline character.

From [the C++ Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)